# In mary document, I see this style of function(assert.fail(actual, expected[, message[, operator[, stackStartFn]]])). How can I understand it?

Tags: function

In many documents, I see this style of function.

```
assert.fail(actual, expected[, message[, operator[, stackStartFn]]])
```

**What style is this?**
**How can I understand it?**

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: for example,node's document. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/assert.html#assert_tracker_calls_fn_exact

Comment: The [ ] indicates things that are optional - this is just something that is used in the documentation.